# Passing BLOB as Parameter causes Error: Operand type clash: image is incompatible with text

Tags: sql-server, delphi, delphi-7, ado

I am working on Delphi 7+ SQL Server 2008 + ADO

I have a table with 4 fields

```
emp_id integer 
Name varchar(50) 
designation varchar(10) 
comment text
```

I am trying to insert data from Delphi

```
 with qryAdoEmployee do
        try
          if not prepared then Prepared := True;
          Parameters.ParamByName('emp_id').Value := 12345;
          Parameters.ParamByName('Name').Value := 'NAME';
          Parameters.ParamByName('designation').Value := 'NEWDesig' ;
```

so i tried below line of code to insert data into **comment** of type **ftBlob**

```
          parameters.ParamByName('comment').Assign(Memo1.Lines);
```

with above line of code it is inserting data into database but it is inserting wrong data like `"???5?????????????????????????"`

so after spending some time on google replaced above line of code with

```
      Len := Length(Memo1.Lines.Text);
      Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
      Stream.Write(Len, SizeOf(Len));
      Stream.Write(PChar(Memo1.Lines.Text)^, Len);
      parameters.ParamByName('comment').LoadFromStream(Stream,ftBlob);
```

above piece of code is throwing error **Operand type clash: image is incompatible with text**

```
    ExecSQL;
    except on E:EDatabaseError do 
      MessageDlg(E.Message, mtError, [mbOK], 0);
    end;
```

Comment: Simply set parameter Value = Memo1.Text

Comment: @kobik : i tried that and it is also giving the same error Operand type clash: image is incompatible with text.

Comment: Is this line correct - parameters.ParamByName('comment').LoadFromStream(Stream,ftBlob); ? as your fieldname is comments text

Comment: I have never came across such problem. How do you define your parameters? if its in design time make sure the parameter `DataType` is `ftMemo`. or set it via code. e.g. `parameters.ParamByName('comment').DataType := ftMemo`

Comment: @RBA: that line is correct. i have edited my question.

Comment: @kobik: parameters are defined at design time and the parameter data type is ftblob.

Comment: @kobik : i changed the parameter type to ftMemo and it's working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server `text` type should map to `ftMemo` in Delphi (not to `ftBlob`).

If you defined the parameters in design time, make sure the `DataType` is set to `ftMemo`, or set it in runtime:

```
parameters.ParamByName('comment').DataType := ftMemo;
```

Then simply assignn the parameter `Value`:

```
parameters.ParamByName('comment').Value := Memo1.Text;
```